# What are applicable uses for JavaScript getters?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, ecmascript-5

I have a need to perform some action whenever an object is changed, and feel that setters might be a good option, and am researching getters and setters for the first time.  While I believe setters can sometime provide benefit, I don't really do so for getters.  Sure, it "might" make my script a little easier to read but at the expense of making it a little more magical, but it seems like one could just as well add whatever functionality the getter would be performing in the function.

I am not asking whether getters are a good thing or not, but just a couple common applications where they provide significant benefit so that I can get my head wrapped around them and be able to identify applicable specific opportunities to use them in the future.

```
var person_w_getter = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set fullName (name) {
        var words = name.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
}

console.log('with getter');
person_w_getter.fullName = 'Jack Franklin';
console.log(person_w_getter.firstName); // Jack
console.log(person_w_getter.lastName) // Franklin

var person_wo_getter = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    getFullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    setfullName: function(name) {
        var words = name.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
}

console.log('without getter');
person_wo_getter.setfullName('Jack Franklin');
console.log(person_wo_getter.firstName); // Jack
console.log(person_wo_getter.lastName) // Franklin
```

Comment: Consider refactoring code where you change `person_w_getter = { fullName: "Jimmy Smith" };` to what you currently have

Comment: Thank you for referencing this previous question, however, I had already read it and it really doesn't give examples where they should be used.

Comment: @Bergi  I don't understand.  Will you please elaborate?  Thanks

Comment: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/getters-setters-javascript/

Comment: @Hackerman  Good article.  Thanks